# What's wrong with my quicksort implementation?

Tags: c++, sorting

just a *quick* (hahaha) question regarding my naive quicksort algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void quicksort2(T array[] , int start, int end){
  int i = start;
  int j = end;
  int temp;
  int pivot = (end - start) / 2;

  // Partioning
  while(i <= j){

    while(array[i] < array[pivot]){
      i++;
    }
    while(array[j] > array[pivot]){
      j--;
    }

    if( i <= j){
      temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }

  // Sorting partions
  if(start <= j){
    quicksort2(array , start , j);
  }
  if(end >= i){
    quicksort2(array , i , end);
  }
}
```

When I run the code it on a test array, it seems that only the left side of the array (the less than side) is sorted and never jumps to sorting the right side and creates an infinite loop.

A bit of a warning before running the code, sometimes it freezes my machine when I run the code on a test array.

Anyway, thanks for the help! Also, this is not for homework (What class with sorting algorithms requires you to learn quicksort right off the bat?)

Comment: Quicksort was the first algorithm I learned in my advanced algorithms class in college, like forever ago.

Comment: Are you running windows?

Comment: Your use of `temp` is kind of dangerous. `temp` is `int` but `array[i];` in `temp = array[i];` is `T`. I would suggest using [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) however stupid it may seem. I wrote it by hand 10 times, 9 good and 1 wrong. Nasty bug. `std::swap(array[i], array[j])` should do the trick and is already templated.

Comment: @luk32 Ah, good catch. I forgot that I was making this a template class since I was testing it with an int array. Thanks.

Comment: @richard No, I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu Linux

Comment: I think, you should swap the pivot element for example with the first element of array at the beginning of the algorithm. No you can change the pivot element with any random number from the array.

Comment: It seems that `array[pivot]` can change..

Comment: Once past the pivot point those 2 little whiles can spin off forever.

Comment: in the if inside the while, if the pivot is not the middle value, then this code is wrong.

Comment: Considering the number of results on this sight by searching for "quicksort [c++]" on this sight (much less the entire web) I'm somewhat shocked you didn't find a implementation that works for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your question with a question.

How do you handle the case where your method is called when start == end?

Each run you divide your subsection around the pivot, so each recursive run, you have 1/2 of the length of last time. So you start by sorting the first half, then the first 1/4, then the first 1/8. Eventually, you'll call the method with start = end = 0. That makes 0 - 0 / 2 the pivot, which is 0.

Run that case through your code, and you'll see that you aren't handling the case where your method tries to sort one entry with itself. It will get stuck in an infinite recursive loop, until it crashes with a...

Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, you're pivot calculation is wrong.

If your start and end are 2 and 4, then 4 - 2 = 2 / 2 = 1. So your pivot index is outside the range of start, end.

Comment: Also the inner loops aren't checkng for crossing (when `i` crosses `j`) and so you can move on.

Comment: @LeeLouviere Ahhh that pivot calculation wasn't what I meant for it to be. I had intended for it to be (left + right)/2. Thanks for catching that. After fixing that and implementing code to deal with the case you described, the code works fine now. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at your use of '='.  I believe you can use >= and <= when comparing to the pivot point, but it's not needed when doing the swap.

Then the kicker is the recursive call - you definitely don't want to use the = there, I think that's the cause of an infinite recursion, which will eventually crash, since j can never be less than the start.  So basically every compare with an =, remove it, and every compare without an =, add one.